# How would I make these two images show side by side HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying to make a Github image link and a Patreon image link show up side by side together. After some searching I found out about black magic called flex, but It's now super spaced apart and I don't want that. How would I fix this? (Code and Images below)

HTML:

```
<div class="promotion">
<div class="column">
  <li><a href="https://github.com/noprojects/noprojects.net">
  <img src="img/github.png" style="width:15%"></a></li>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <li><a href="https://patreon.com/noprojects">
  <img src="img/patreon.png" style="width:15%"></a></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

[image: css]

What's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your list item `<li>` tags aren't in a list tag `<ul>`.

```
<div class="promotion">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://github.com/noprojects/noprojects.net">
      <img src="img/github.png" style="width:15%">
    </a>
    <a href="https://patreon.com/noprojects">
      <img src="img/patreon.png" style="width:15%">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the `.promotion li` css values to the `.column` class.

Comment: thanks for helping it actually worked ^^